# python subprocess - cygwin call - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: python, subprocess, cygwin

I am trying to run a .exe file on Windows 10, by calling it inside of a Python 3.8 script with subprocess. I want to execute everything on Cygwin.

The following is my Python function doing that:

```
os.chdir(r"c:\cygwin64\bin")
cmd = ["bash", "-c", 'cd "C:/Users/usr/file"; ./myexefile']
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This will give me the error

```
C:/Users/usr/file/myexefile.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

While I was trying to figure out, what is the problem,

- I executed the file on the cygwin shell directly, without a problem
- I ran other commands (cd, pwd,...) with said python script, again without a problem.

I read some solutions of that specific error, in other contexts, saying one is supposed to change path variables, but as the function call works within Cygwin, I don't think this works.

I hope someone can help me, I'm very new to this topic.

EDIT: I also discovered, that the command "ls" does not work. "cd", "pwd" do work.

Comment: what python, Cygwin or Windows one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:** I fixed it with adding `C:/cygwin64/bin` to the `Path` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Windows python trying to run a Cygwin shell

```
os.chdir(r"c:\cygwin64\bin")
cmd = ["bash", "-c", 'cd "C:/Users/usr/file"; ./myexefile']
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

assuming that `myexefile` is a Cygwin program, as the bash is not run with login option
the PATH is not correctly set and the needed shared lib are not found.

If you need to know which DLLs are needed for a program or shared lib:

```
$ objdump -x octave-5.2.0.exe |grep "DLL Name:"
        DLL Name: cygwin1.dll
        DLL Name: cygX11-6.dll
        DLL Name: cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
        DLL Name: cygstdc++-6.dll
        DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
```

Comment: My .exe file only requires cygwin1.dll and KERNEL32.dll, which are both installed. How can I set the PATH correctly? Also, I'm not quite sure, what you mean with the bash login option. Thank you for your help

Comment: `bash -l -c ...`    https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: adding -l or other options will give me the error "bash: - : invalid option". i'm very insecure how I can move on and repair it, i have the feeling it can't be that hard to fix